# How to use Union query with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

This MySQL query Has union and Normalized I don't Know how to write laravel Query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT val
FROM
(
    SELECT 'date' date_type, date val FROM user_presentation
    UNION
    SELECT 'accept_date', accept_date FROM user_presentation
    UNION
    SELECT 'question_date', question_date FROM user_presentation
    UNION
    SELECT 'success_date', success_date FROM user_presentation
) normalized;
```

Comment: Can you be more clear, please?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#unions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may chain a series of unions in your Laravel code:

```
$first = DB::table('user_presentation')
    ->select('date');

$second = DB::table('user_presentation')
    ->select('accept_date');

$third = DB::table('user_presentation')
    ->select('question_date');

$fourth = DB::table('user_presentation')
    ->select('success_date AS val')
    ->union($first)
    ->union($second)
    ->union($third)
    ->get();
```

Note the above code actually corresponds to this query:

```
SELECT date AS val FROM user_presentation UNION
SELECT accept_date FROM user_presentation UNION
SELECT question_date FROM user_presentation UNION
SELECT success_date FROM user_presentation;
```

Also, the `DISTINCT` subquery you have should not be necessary, as the union query itself should remove all duplicate date values.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$userP = UserPresentation::get()
->only('date', 'accept_date', 'question_date', 'success_date')
->unique();
```

The 100% Laravel Way, using Collection, this one will select all four dates together, and Laravel Collection will find the unique rows from these selections.